# Read a file as base 64 to store it into a state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, filereader

I try to store base64 value of an input file into a state variable. But, the problem is getting base64 is asynchronous. So I got some trouble in console.logs...

Here is my code :

```
getBase64(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
            arrayStamp.push({photo: reader.result})
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
          console.log('Error: ', error);
        };
    }

handleFiles(event){
        for(var x = 0; x < event.target.files.length; x++){
            this.getBase64(event.target.files[x])
        }
        console.log(arrayStamp)
        for(var x = 0; x < arrayStamp.slice.length; x++){
            console.log(arrayStamp[x])
        }
    }
```

This gives me :

[image]

The variable arrayStamp is declared before the class, like this :

```
let arrayStamp = []

    class Photos extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props)

            this._child = React.createRef();

            this.state = {
                modalTitle: '',
                alpha3: '',
    ...
```

How should I be able to browse the array, it seems that it is empty, but I got values in console.log....

I used some libraries like react-file-reader but no one gives me the possibility to got the original file + base64.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, this is beceause `readAsDataURL()` is asynchronous, and so you'll have to wait until all files have been read before your array can be used.

```
const arrayStamp = [];

handleFiles(event) {
    let files = event.target.files,
        i = 0,
        reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        arrayStamp.push({photo: reader.result})

        if (i++ < files.length - 1) {
            // Read the next file.
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        } else {
            // All files have been read.
            console.log(arrayStamp);
        }
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
}
```

I haven't tested this but should give you the idea. Essentially you're using one fileReader to load each file in sequence and push the result to your array.

Answer (score 0):

in functionsDirectory

```
export function getBase64(img, callback) {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.addEventListener('load', () => callback(reader.result))
    reader.readAsDataURL(img)
}
```

And use this:

```
import { getBase64 } from 'functionsDirectory'

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  getBase64(
     files[i],
     base64 => { arrayStamp.push({base64, file: files[i]}) }
  )         
}
```